# Submitting iOS 5 apps during the transition to iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store, ios6

Has Apple made any announcement as to how long they will accept apps built using the iOS 5 SDK (as opposed to the new iOS 6)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and they don't tend to make any such announcements.

That said, you'd normally build against the iOS 6 SDK and simply set a deployment target of 5.0. Numerous bug fixes usually occur in the compiler-side part of the SDK between releases that don't relate to new features.

The legacy simulators will allow you to continue to test appropriately directly on your computer and obviously you can continue to connect up a real iOS 5 device.

The real question is when Apple will stop accepting 5.x deployment targets for the App Store. As they still accept 4.0 now I suspect that'll be a while.

Comment: So, right now we should change our apps to compile against iOS 6 SDK?

Comment: Yep — it's recommended just to leave the relevant box to use the latest SDK. The deployment target and your own testing are the only things you should alter to make your app available for an earlier version of the OS.